# how to choose how many letters to abbreviate a word in python

Tags: python

```
`##
# Returns the abbreviated version of a string.
# @param string the string from which the abbreviation is constructed
# @param size the maximum number of characters in the abbreviation
# @returns the abbreviated version of the string, which is formed from 
#       size number of characters at the front of of the string
#
`



`def abbreviation(string, size) :



testStr = input()
testSize = int(input())
print(abbreviation(testStr, testSize))`
```

Above is the problem and the already written code is unchangeable, meaning I have to code around it, for my Computer Science class.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to code the maximum amount of size abbreviation so that each time I input that i can then abbreviate that amount, to then return it.

```
`def abbreviation(string, size) :
    _len = len(string);

    # Print 1st character
    print(string[range(0, testSize)], end="");

testStr = input()
testSize = int(input())
print(abbreviation(testStr, testSize))`
```

I've tried using range to be how much I want to abbreviate but that doesn't work.

```
`def abbreviation(string, size) :
    _len = len(string);

    # Print 1st character
    print(string[0], end="");


testStr = input()
testSize = int(input())
print(abbreviation(testStr, testSize))`
```

using got me to receive the first letter to abbreviate doesn't allow me to choose what the max amount of abbreviation I want.

Comment: What does "abbreviated" here mean? The same as truncated?

Comment: Read any string manipulation tutorial? `string[:size]`

Comment: As an advisory, conventional [Python coding style](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#introduction) does not have a space between the arguments and the necessary `:` at the end, as in `def f(x):` not `def f(x) :`.

Comment: @tadman what part of "unchangeable" do you not understand?  Do you think they're going to get extra points for pointing out their teacher has bad coding style?

Comment: @MarkRansom The teacher can teach however they want, in whatever bizarre style they prefer, and grade accordingly, but that doesn't mean we should let people pick up these habits unknowingly.

Comment: Why do you have a `print` in your function?  That seems redundant since the program already prints the return value.

Comment: This is clearly an exercise in slicing. Here's a good resource: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html

Comment: @MarkRansom I had print in my function to test at the time how to output being very late and very new at this, I wasn't thinking  the clearest

Comment: @DarkKnight this was helpful with learning about slicing so in the future I can use it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with putting extra prints in your function as a debugging aid, I still do it to this day.  The purpose of my question was to get you to think about what you're doing, and I'm happy to see you doing it.  That's the foundation of learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the instructions, when it says *"returns the abbreviated version of the string"*, it means your function should use the `return` statement, and not `print`

```
def abbreviation(string, size):
    if size <= 0:
        # if the length of the abbreviation(size) is negative or zero return empty string
        return ""
    elif size >= len(string):
        # if the size is bigger than the length of your string, return the full string 
        return string
    else:
        # if the size is small (as it should be), then return the sliced string
        return string[:size]


testStr = input()
testSize = int(input())
print(abbreviation(testStr, testSize))
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot learning  the functions has been a bit challenge with first figuring out that return and what to return has confused me a bunch I'm starting to get a hang of it.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can use String Slicing in Python. Using the syntax `string[a:b]` you can select the characters in your string from index `a` to `b-1`.

```py
my_string = "hello world!"

# Get the first 3 characters from my_string
print(my_string[0:3]) // result: "hel"

# Get the first X characters from my_string
print(my_string[0:X])
```

Note, Python is 0-indexed, so the first character is 0, 2nd is 1, and so on. Writing `my_string[1:3]` would return the 2nd and 3rd characters of the string.

So if you want to abbreviate your string to size `testSize`, use the following slice

```py
abbreviated_string = testStr[0:testSize]
```

Comment: Learning of Slicing has helped so much thank you.